# Decoding JSON using php and curl

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

I'm having a problem making an array for `foreach(){}` for the json that uses curl to get a json from youtube. I already have the json decoded for the curl part but when I tried to decode using true to get the array for `json_decode`, I can't seem to get the array on each of the array output. How do i get each item and put it out as an array?

I already tried this website:
[Decoding JSON using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550366/decoding-json-using-php)
to get some help but its not working.

```
////////youtube api////////
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&order=rating&q=resident%20evil&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&key=",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) 
    {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else 
    {
    echo $response;
        //echo json_decode($response, true);

        $json_array = (array) json_decode($response, true);

        foreach($json_array as $json)
            {
                //echo $json['title']; // you can access your key value like this if result is array
                //echo $json['kind'][0];
               // echo $json['id'];
                //echo $json->title; // you can access your key value like this if result is object
//                
//                $error =  json_last_error();
//                var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);

                //print $json->response->kind[0];

                //echo $error;
            }

}
/////youtube api//////


OUTPUT JSON:

{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/l9fetqKKtU8Szcemtrp1SkvVqXU\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
    "regionCode": "US",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1000000,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [{
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/ycGvBReC7A0jFAVEINKomlikUpk\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "_SzgAVZUl78"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2019-10-04T15:51:00.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCeXaWu8hgGxjnOwM2r4Zu_A",
            "title": "Resident Evil llega a Monster Hunter World: Iceborne",
            "description": "Cazadores algo sobrenatural esta sucediento en Monster Hunter: World, y es por ello que Leon y Claire de Resident Evil, llegarán al juego este noviembre ...",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_SzgAVZUl78/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_SzgAVZUl78/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_SzgAVZUl78/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Arata Latam",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
        }
    }, {
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/Cz2nZtIJefFeGMYIUIS52KQzRsI\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "gE2EGGstC_4"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2018-02-04T18:29:52.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCaddCVMWjvDI_rfWZML8qvw",
            "title": "RESIDENT EVIL - REVELATIONS [#12] THE QUEEN IS DEAD",
            "description": "WALKTHROUGH OF ALL EPISODES OF THE QUEEN IS DEAD. NO COMMENTARY. NORMAL DIFFICULTY. HD.",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gE2EGGstC_4/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gE2EGGstC_4/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gE2EGGstC_4/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Wormwoodmachine",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
        }
    }, {
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/pYPZMJ3MHu9g7tghE7einGWzLSo\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "4w7ISumKoe4"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2010-08-01T20:01:50.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCbaXoO4Lnw826akSES9J51w",
            "title": "Biohazard / Resident Evil - Sega Saturn",
            "description": "http://www.thearchive.tk.",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4w7ISumKoe4/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4w7ISumKoe4/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4w7ISumKoe4/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Nakian",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
        }
    }, {
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/uEOwZoLXlcKYQTs2Vvp-06qtS4Q\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "1g2ems2cW2I"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2019-01-28T15:51:45.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCAbZF8x8TbsooEWfJ0fA-Cw",
            "title": "Resident Evil 2 Remake Last Judgment",
            "description": "Resident Evil 2 Remake (Soundtrack)",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1g2ems2cW2I/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1g2ems2cW2I/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1g2ems2cW2I/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Black Pain",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
        }
    }, {
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/hyeTWi-c-0xib8C7ZRuxjZGT7bE\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "tud8tUdC7OM"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2019-10-04T20:06:42.000Z",
            "channelId": "UChWTmWEZBWLroVBsB9MvU2A",
            "title": "Resident Evil 2 R2MAKE Hardcore Leon B",
            "description": "Thy kingdom come, Thy will be done. We play all kinds of games. Silent hill, batman, Resident evil, metal gear, h1z1, fortnite, roblox, dead space, evil within, god ...",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tud8tUdC7OM/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tud8tUdC7OM/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tud8tUdC7OM/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "Tu Papi Leon",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please put here result of youtube api for helping better to understand what you want :)

Comment: you code is fine, also (array) before json_decode($response, true) is useless , it is already an array. maybe you have a problem with receiving json.

Comment: Your JSON is an object, not an array

Comment: items is an array right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping in the top level array. You need to loop in the `items` index:

```
foreach($json_array['items'] as $json){
    echo $json['snippet']['title']."<br>";
    echo $json['kind'];           
}
```